# Using the base method in the overridden method

Tags: javascript

I need to override a method and use the base method in the overridden method.

I came up with this so far

http://jsfiddle.net/tyR8Q/

but I'm wondering if this is the best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The key is using the method apply of function.

This is my solution:

```
function Super(x){this.x = x}
Super.prototype.method = function(y){console.log("Super " + this.x + y)}

function Sub(x){Super.apply(this, arguments)}
Sub.prototype = Object.create(Super.prototype)
Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub
Sub.prototype.method = function(y){
  Super.prototype.method.apply(this, arguments)
}

var sub = new Sub(1)
sub.method(2)
```

I tried to follow the standard as close as possible, defining fields of the class inside the constructor, methods in the prototype, and creating a new function for the sub class.

Note that I call the constructor and method of the super class.